# Distributed Data Parallel (DDP) Batch size

Tags: pytorch, ddp

Suppose, I use 2 gpus in a DDP setting.

So, if I intend to use 16 as a batch size if I run the experiment on a single gpu,

should I give 8 as a batch size, or 16 as a batch size in case of using 2 gpus with DDP setting??

Does 16 is divided into 8 and 8 automatically?

Thank you -!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html):

- the application of the given module by **splitting the input** across the specified devices
- The batch size should be larger than the number of GPUs used locally
- each replica handles a portion of the input

If you use 16 as batch-size, it will be divided automatically between the two gpus.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't be split automatically.
When you set `batch_size=8` under DDP mode, each GPU will receive dataset with `batch_size=8`, so the global `batch_size=16`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33443275)

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with Deusy94's answer.

If I understand correctly according to pytorch's [official example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/imagenet/main.py#L160) using distributed data parallel (ddp) at line 160:

```
args.batch_size = int(args.batch_size / ngpus_per_node)
```

the batch size when you instantiate the DataLoader is the batch size for a single process/single node.

Note that in the argparser the comment was:

```
parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size', default=256, type=int,
                metavar='N',
                help='mini-batch size (default: 256), this is the total '
                     'batch size of all GPUs on the current node when '
                     'using Data Parallel or Distributed Data Parallel')
```

Hence, let's say you have passed --batch-size 16 here and you have two GPUs, the `args.batch_size` will be updated to 8 manually (divided by number of GPUs) in Line 160 above, and the actual dataloader you created is with batch_size of 8 - which is the dataloader for individual GPUs.

Therefore, if you create dataloader with `DataLoader(datasetm batch_size=16)`, and you start the DDP with 2 GPUs, each GPU will proceed with batch_size=16 and your global batch_size will be 32.

This is different with `DataParallel` which has a [gather/scatter procedure](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/parallel/scatter_gather.py), such that your batch is automatically scattered into equal size of chunks for each GPUs (i.e., `DataLoader(datasetm batch_size=16)` --> each GPU gets 8).

Eather way, it's quite easy to verify it if you iterate the dataloader with a progress bar (e.g., tqdm) to log how many steps it needed to traverse all batches (i.e., number of batches), and you can always compute which of the equation is True: `batch_size * num_batches == dataset_size` or `num_gpu * batch_size * num_batches == dataset_size`.